# Jquery data attribute value undefined

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline filter-submit margin-bottom" data-type="Invoice Generate" onclick="show_modal()"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></button>
```

jQuery:

```
function show_modal(){
    alert($(this).data("type"));
    $('#basic').modal('show'); 
}
```

Output:

```
Undefined
```

Expected Output:

```
Invoice Generate
```

Anyone can please tell me why it alerting undefined and How can I resolve it?

Comment: For what purpose you are using modal?

Comment: @Ravigohil What does that matter?

Answer (score 5):

You `show_modal` function don't know what `$(this)` is. so add `this` to `onclick="show_modal()"` like `onclick="show_modal(this)"`

Then you, of course, has to update your function as well as below:

```
function show_modal(obj){
    alert($(obj).data("type"));
    $('#basic').modal('show'); 
}
```

```js
function show_modal(obj){
    alert($(obj).data("type"));
    $('#basic').modal('show'); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline filter-submit margin-bottom" data-type="Invoice Generate" onclick="show_modal(this)"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></button>
```

Comment: Sir it working here but not working on my link can you please check it. http://ec2-52-66-146-251.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/Purvi/index.php/Notification/Notification_list

Comment: @RushabhShah You get the following error in your console `jQuery is not defined` means your jquery is not loaded correctly

Comment: Actually I forgot to add obj in this line show_modal(obj) now I added and it working fine thanks for your help.

Comment: @RushabhShah No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

you are calling function you have to pass this will function like

```
<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline filter-submit margin-bottom" data-type="Invoice Generate" onclick="show_modal()"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></button>
```

And in JS

```
function show_modal(ob){
    alert($(ob).data("type"));
    $('#basic').modal('show'); 
}
```

Comment: using `this` in `show_modal(this)` will not work, since this is a reserved word.

Comment: Your still missing to add something to `show_modal()`

Comment: if #basic is your model then you have to use     $('#basic').show() instead of     $('#basic').modal('show');

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to use `$(this)` attach an event handler to the element using it's class or id like this..

```
$('.filter-submit').on('click', function(){
  alert($(this).data("type"));
})
```

```js
$('.filter-submit').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).data("type"));
  //$('#basic').modal('show');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline filter-submit margin-bottom" data-type="Invoice Generate"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is your solution

```
<button class="btn btn-sm green btn-outline filter-submit margin-bottom" data-type="Invoice Generate" onclick="show_modal(this)"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></button>

<script>
   function show_modal(ele){

      alert($(ele).data("type"));
      $('#basic').modal('show'); 
   }
</script>
```